# What's the recommended reading order for Fall of the Mutants (X-Men)?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men, suggested-order

I've been searching the net for some definitive (or even a suggestion) for a reading order for this X-Men crossover but I'm coming up blank.

The best one I saw was from this [site](http://crushingkrisis.com/collecting-x-men-comic-books-as-graphic-novels/x-men-reading-order-guide/x-men-reading-order-guide-era-04/) but I'm a bit confused on how to understand it.

Any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]
[image]

This is a very different type of cross-over than other big X-Men events in-that the plots of each individual title do not intersect, **so there is no such thing as a correct read order... per se**. Each **series** should be read on its own as the concept for this event was more *'a dynamic change for each title happening at the same time'* than a story which starts in one title to be continued in others. Still, as you read through the books in this event it is revealed that some of the villains which participate in FotM have larger connections/concerns with others baddies.

**The main issues involved are**:

- **Uncanny X-Men (1st series) #s 225-227**
- **New Mutants (1st series) #s 59-61**
- **X-Factor #s 24-26**

There were a number of 'TIE-IN' issues: **Captain America #339**, **Daredevil #252**, **Fantastic Four #312**, **Hulk #340** and **Power Pack #34** Which are not officially part of the cross-over event, but they were released at the same time and show the effects the **Horsemen’s Attack** has on some part of New York, or other MARVEL heroes fighting them. While in the case of Hulk, it follows him lending a hand to the X-Men in Dallas (well help *isn't* really what he does).  Also Hulk #s 336-337 have some lead-up as they involve a run-in with X-Factor, but they -like many of the other tie-in's listed above- do not fly the "Fall of the Mutants" banner-head.

This is the [reading order](http://www.uncannyxmen.net/db/crossover/showquestion.asp?fldAuto=217) most follow:

- Uncanny X-Men (1st series) #225
- Uncanny X-Men (1st series) #226
- Uncanny X-Men (1st series) #227

[image]

---

- New Mutants (1st series) #59
- New Mutants (1st series) #60
- New Mutants (1st series) #61

[image]

---

- X-Factor #24
- X-Factor #25
- X-Factor #26

[image] [image]

---

If you're looking to read all the books directly connected to the **FotM Event** I would suggest the **X-Men: Fall of the Mutants Omnibus [ISBN 0-7851-5312-8]**, though much of what you will be reading, even there, has connections further back having been plotted for months with strings going back years in some cases: Naze, The Dire Wraiths & Adversary, the main focus in the X-Men's aspect of FotM, were seen as far back as **Uncanny #188** while the mystery of Bird-Brain, which brought the **New Mutants** to *Paradise Island* for their FotM story, started back in issue **#55** of that series and finally Angel's death, **X-Factor #s 15-16**, as well as the new character of Apocalypse, first seen in issue **#6**, directly effect the Original X-Men's focus in the FotM event.

**Here's the Wiki Page for [Fall of the Mutants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_of_the_Mutants)** which *might* help clear some things up...

[image] [image]